# Combining job results in celery

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I'm working on a software upgrade system using celery. I have a use case that I'm struggling to implement cleanly. Here are my jobs:

> **device_software_updates(device_id)**
>
> ```
> returns a list of software updates that need to be installed on a device
> ```
>
> **installed_device_software(device_id)**
>
> ```
> returns the software modules that are currently installed on a device
> ```
>
> **latest_device_software(device_id)**
>
> ```
> returns the latest software versions available for a device
> ```
>
> **software_updates(installed_software, latest_software)**
>
> ```
> returns the latest software modules that are not installed
> ```

In pure python, the implementation of device_software_updates might look like

```
def device_software_updates(device_id):
    return software_updates(installed_device_software(device_id),
                            latest_device_software(device_id))
```

What is the cleanest way to implement this in Celery 3.0? I'd like to do something using groups. My current implementation looks like this:

```
def device_software_updates(device_id):
    return (
        group(installed_device_software.s(device_id),
              latest_device_software.s(device_id)) |
        software_updates.s()
    )()
```

Unfortunately, this means that the argspec of software_updates is `software_updates(arg_list)` which is not ideal.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that using a *chord* would be the right way to handle this.

According the the Celery documentation at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups,

> A chord is a task that only executes after all of the tasks in a
> taskset have finished executing.
>
> ...
>
> A chord is just like a group but with a callback. A chord consists of
> a header group and a body, where the body is a task that should
> execute after all of the tasks in the header are complete.

Here is a broken down, line by line example (from the Celery documentation)

```
callback = tsum.subtask()
header = [add.subtask((i, i)) for i in xrange(100)]
result = chord(header)(callback)
result.get()
```

In your case, you could do something similar, like:

```
@celery.task
def device_software_updates():
    callback = software_updates.subtask()
    header = [
              installed_device_software.subtask(device_id), 
              latest_device_software.s(device_id) 
             ]
    result = chord(header)(callback)
    return result.get()
```

Comment: You should never call result.get() from inside the task, you might get a deadlock. http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/result.html.